# in pine-script in DCA strategy between two strategy.entry determining candle range

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

In pine script V5, our DCA strategy is opening long positions by too close candles.

As opening new position after last position, I want to determine the ranges among candles. For instance, after providing ten candles circumstance, it must be able to open new positions.

Waiting for your help..
Best Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save to an int (let's say *entryIndex*) the bar_index when opening a deal, and afterwards check

```
if (bar_index - entryIndex >= 10)
```

Comment: Hello
I applied but it didn't work. I guess I failed.
Can you apply it to a strategy as an example?
Kind regards

Comment: @turkprinting Did I understand correctly that you simply want to wait at least ten bars since opening a DCA deal before your code considers adding funds to the deal?

Comment: I'm new to pine script.
I applied but it didn't work.
Can you show an example application?
Regards

Comment: yes you got it right.

Comment: I guess I am not able to save the "entryIndex" first.

Comment: @turkprinting I'm not near my PC right now, but basically the bar_index is a reference to the index of a specific bar inside the entirety of the chart. So if you declare varip int entryIndex = na, and later when you enter a deal also add to that block of code enteryIndex := bar_index, you will have an index stamp for when was the deal opened. You can afterwards have an if conditional using (bar_index - entryIndex == 10) to execute a certain piece of code only after 10 bars have passed. You should also add some boolean that states whether you've already reinvested during this point in time.

Comment: @turkprinting You also may want to reassign the bar_index value to entryIndex whenever you've added funds so you would know how many bars have passed since investing.